# Making two arrays the same size by grouping

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I have 2 arrays with the same size, the first one represents time and the second one represents distance i want to group by the first one so each group will have only the same integer values (The floats between two integers)

Heres my orginal time array:

```
time=[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,1.9]
```

And heres my distance array:

```
distance=[1,2,4,5.5,7.8,9.6,10,11,11.6,11.9]
```

so in the time array after grouping by same intger im getting this :

```
time=[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8],[1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,1.9]
```

the first subgroup contain `4 elements` and the second contain `6 elements`
so the distance groups should be contain `4 then 6 elements` accordingly
like this :

```
distance=[1,2,4,5.5],[7.8,9.6,10,11,11.6,11.9]
```

so the size of each group will be same size of the distance groups

Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you want:

```
s=set([int(i) for i in time])
timesplit={i:[] for i in s}
for i in time:
    k=int(i)
    timesplit[k].append(i)

timelengths=[len(i) for i in timesplit.values()]

distances=[]
for i in timelengths:
    distances.append(distance[:i])
    distance=distance[i:]

res_times=list(timesplit.values())
res_distances=distances

print(res_times)
print(res_distances)
```

Output:

```
[[0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8],[1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,1.9]]
[[1,2,4,5.5],[7.8,9.6,10,11,11.6,11.9]]
```

Comment: This is very helpful
but when i was trying to plot them but im getting this message: 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
Any idead?

Comment: What are you trying to plot?
Each result is a list of lists and you cannot plot them directly. You can plot their items individually (eg res_times[0] with res_distances[0] etc)